# How to get the selected value from a asp:DropdownList using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have the following code and it gives me the text but not the value. What is wrong and how do I fix it?

```
 function pageLoad() {
       $('#<%=dpEmploymentStatus.ClientID%>').change(function() {

       alert($('#<%=dpEmploymentStatus.ClientID%>' + ' option:selected').text());


       }).change();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` instead of `text()`.